# File upload change event trigeeting too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, meteor

In my template I have this code

```
<input type="file" id="FeedImageUpload" name="upload" style="visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px" multiple />

<a onclick="document.getElementById('FeedImageUpload').click();"><i class="mdi-image-photo-camera panel-icon"></i></a>
```

In my template events I have this code

```
'change #FeedImageUpload':function(event){
        console.log('change');
    }
```

when I try to upload the files, the change event is firing hundreds of times sometimes thousands
[image]
I want to upload image to server on that event,I don't want to upload image so many times

Comment: @Hungnh1704, Is it the issue, what if I want to upload multiple images with the same code

Comment: The problem still exists, even I removed the multiple

Comment: i think the multiple="", is just allow multiple files to be added via one input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution.

chaining the event form change to click.

```
'click #FeedImageUpload':function(event){
        console.log('change');
    }
```

If you don't want to have an input style, try this JSFiddle

[This](http://%20jsfiddle.net/fengelz/28x7Y) or [This](http://%20jsfiddle.net/timtate/3XbGd)